# Is there a String eql?

Tags: ruby, string, methods, equals

```
myParagraph = "Th ie f should be uppercase f"

swearWords = ["e","f"]

swearWords.each { |x|
  if myParagraph.include?(x)
    myParagraph.gsub!(x, x.upcase)
  end
}   

puts myParagraph
```

Returns `"Th iE F should bE uppErcasE F"`. Thats fine but if I replace `.include?` with `.eql?`, I was expecting the result to be `"Th ie F should be uppercase F"` but I got `"Th ie f should be uppercase f"`. Why is this? The `.eql` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I understood almost nothing

Comment: You are asking if `"Th ie f should be uppercase f"` either "includes" `x` or is equal to `x`. The entire sentence will never be equal to the single character.

Comment: Yeah my bad I thought it iterated through each word

Answer (score 0):

`eql?` doesn't work because you are comparing a multi-character string to a one-character string, and those will never be equal.

Answer (score 0):

`eql?` returns true only if `myParagraph` and `x` are the same object.